# Inbound and outbound ports needs to be same or not

Tags: amazon-web-services, sockets, networking, port, vpc

Senario:
There are two servers running on different VPCs. Both servers are publically available.
Server-one(e.g. Public IP:13.126.233.125) is hosting one file on 8000 port and port 8000 inbound is open on all firewall installed on the server and security group.

Server-two wants to get that file with "wget command". Port 80 outbound Server-two is open. I tried to do "wget http://13.126.233.125:8000/file.txt", it shows connection refused. I had to open port 8000 in outbound of Server-two to make this work.

As per my logic, this should have worked without adding 8000 in out-bound list. Server-one is hosting on 8000, It's not compulsory for server-two to start the connection from 8000 port. server-two can use any ephemeral ports or port 80 as this is http connection.

Please explain why it's required to open out-bound port 8000 on server-two.

Comment: I found an interesting article that you might want to read : http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPClientEphemeralPortsandClientServerApplicatio.htm

Comment: According to link "To know where to send the reply, the server must know the port number the client is using. This is supplied by the client as the Source Port in the request, and then used by the server as the destination port to send the reply."  Will client use Source Port(ephemeral port) to initiate a request or it will use some different port to initiate a request and then just get a response back on the ephemeral port?

Answer (score 9):

HTTP is a protocol that sits on top of TCP. Using port 80 is a convention and not a requirement. You can run HTTP (and HTTPS) on any port you want that is available. The way that TCP works, is that a process will open a TCP port (say 8000) and then "listen" on that port for connection attempts from other systems (local or remote). If you try to connect using port 80 on a system listening on port 8000, you will either connect to the wrong service or get connection refused. Only after the connection is accepted does ephemeral ports come into action.

If server A is running a service listening on port 8000, then server B needs to connect to server A using port 8000. This means that server B needs port 8000 open outbound in order to connect to port 8000.

In normal usage, you set (restrict) the inbound ports in a security group and allow ALL outbound ports. Only restrict outbound ports if you understand how TCP works and know exactly what you are doing and why. Otherwise leave all outbound ports open.

There are a few reasons to control outbound ports. For example, to prevent an instance from performing updates, to prevent an instance from communicating if was breached, etc. If you are controlling this level of communications, then you also need to understand how NACLs work and how to use each one.

AWS has some pretty good documentation that explains how security groups and NACLs work and how to use them.

Comment: +1 Would further add that ephemeral ports are very high numbered ports and in practice only become more important to pay attention to when you are using dynamic port mapping in setups such as containerization of services.

Answer (score 0):

Outbound firewalls are used to limit the connections to external services from within the network. That is why by default all outbound connections are enabled and inbound connections are disabled.

In this case, setting an outbound firewall on server 2 prohibits server 2 from making connections to port 8000 (and all others, except 80) of server 1. It is regardless of the port from which the connection is initiated.